# Genuine elementary OS installation

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing elementary OS.

It asked me for a product key and said there must be some Certificate of Authenticity on it, like this: [image: Arch Linux Certificate of Authenticity example]

I have tried visiting URL on this image, but it is replaced with some nonsense. Where is it located?

Answer (score 2):

elementary OS does not use product keys or prompt for product keys.

Please ensure that what you have downloaded and are trying to install originates from [the elementary website](https://elementary.io/) and that the checksum matches as per [the installation guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation).